# CSS padding/margin issue in Opera 12.02?

Tags: css, cross-browser, containers, opera

Hi StackOverflow users,

I'm working on a new personal website for myself, and have found that Opera 12.02 (I'm on Mac) is being very tricky. For some reason the positioning is completely off for pretty much everything, save for the container that it's all packaged in. So I'm guessing this is a padding/margin/line-height issue. Here's the site: http://www.tommaxwell.me. Can someone help me out?

CSS:

```
    body {
padding: 0 auto;
margin: 0 auto;


}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
* { font-weight: 100; }
h1, h2 
}



#sitecontent {
display: block;
width: 780px;
padding-top: 150px;
margin: 0 auto;
}


#sitecontent .leftsidebar {
float: left;
width: 150px;
}

#profilepic {
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
#sitecontent .leftsidebar ul {
position: relative;
top: -5px;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: 'Cantora One', sans-serif;

 }


#sitecontent a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #3f83ca;
}




#sitecontent .leftsidebar ul li{
margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#sitecontent a:hover {
opacity: 0.9;

}

#sitecontent .rightsidebar {
float: right;
width: 600px;

}

#sitecontent .rightsidebar > h1 {
font-size:60px;
color: #3f83ca;
line-height: 0;
font-family: 'Cantora One', sans-serif;

}

#sitecontent .rightsidebar > h2 {
line-height: 10px;
color: #38414f;
font-family: 'Cantora One', sans-serif;
}

#sitecontent .rightsidebar > p {
padding-top: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
font-family: 'Cantora One', sans-serif;



}

#secondparagraph {
opacity: 0.5;


}

#secondparagraph:hover {
color:#3f83ca;
opacity: 1.0;

}

#secondparagraph a {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: FYI, your `@-moz-document` rule has a dangling selector.

Comment: @BoltClock - Oh yeah, I fixed that after posting.

Answer (score -1):

Add to `overflow:hidden` in your `#sitecontent` in css

as like this

```
#sitecontent{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked.

```
x:-o-prefocus, h1 {
padding-top: 22px;
}

x:-o-prefocus, h2 {
margin-top: -24px;
}
```

Comment: IE7 is known to pick that up.